# Laravel 5.3 - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3, soft-delete

Laravel version that I am using is 5.3.
And I am already using the trait SoftDeletes and it was imported correctly too.

```
namespace App\Models; 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Reference extends Model {

  use SoftDeletes;

  protected $fillable = [
    'client_id',
    'email'
  ];
}
```

When I use the methods onlyTrashed() or withTrashed() I get the error.

```
$reference = Reference::withTrashed()->get();
```

or

```
$reference = Reference::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

Error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450: 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()
```

Some methods like that are working:

```
Reference::find(1)->delete();
Reference::find(1)->restore();
Reference::find(1)->trashed();
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you don't have a `deleted_at` column in your table.  Did you create your reference table with a column in your migration like the following?

`$table->softDeletes()`;

Even though you added Eloquent\Softdeletes on your model it will still fail with the error message you got if the actual table does not have that column.

Comment: I have created the migration with $table->softDeletes(). The other methods are working. The method delete() is updating the deleted_at column to the timestamp. This is strange.

Comment: And when I run the Reference::all(), returns all rows, until the row deleted (with timestamp at the deleted_at);